# Django Windows IIS Single Sign On

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm currently working on a Django App that has all reporting dashboards for 11 different divisions. One of the web development requirements of our company is a single sign-on. My app is currently hosted via Windows IIS and I have a database resource where I can grab all active users for our company.

However, I have searched the net for tutorials on how to do this in my Django app but with no success. If you could provide me a url or at least an advice on how to do this, I would definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign on from an app in your company or something like Google? For social single sign on you could take a look at the https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/tree/master/social_django, or use that to create your own.